# Iterate Cypher results in Scala

Tags: scala, neo4j

I am using Neo4j 1.9 embedded with scale.
When run this code, i have an error in the row 5 with this message:
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons cannot be cast to org.neo4j.graphdb.Node

This is my code:

```
 val _shortestPathQuery= """
    START n=node:node_auto_index(tag="body"),m=node:node_auto_index(tag="#text")
    MATCH p=shortestPath( n-[r:FATHER*..]-m )
    WHERE m.text =~ '.*%s.*'
    RETURN NODES(p) as pathnodes;
    """.stripMargin.format(toSearch)

    val tx = graphDb.beginTx()
    val result = engine.execute( _shortestPathQuery )

    val decPath:Iterator[org.neo4j.graphdb.Node]  = result.columnAs("pathnodes")

    for ( node:org.neo4j.graphdb.Node <- decPath)
    {
       println(node + ": " + node.getProperty("nodeid") + " " + node.getId)
    }
```

I have found many java code, but i unable to convert it in Scala.

If i print the result: println(result.dumpToString()) i see the correct rows.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return a column which contains an `Iterable` of nodes.

So perhaps use:

```
val _shortestPathQuery= """
    START n=node:node_auto_index(tag="body"),m=node:node_auto_index(tag="#text")
    MATCH p=shortestPath( n-[r:FATHER*..]-m )
    WHERE m.text =~ '.*%s.*'
    RETURN NODES(p) as pathnodes;
    """.stripMargin.format(toSearch)

    val tx = graphDb.beginTx()
    val result = engine.execute( _shortestPathQuery )

    val decPath:Iterator[Iterator[org.neo4j.graphdb.Node]]  = result.columnAs("pathnodes")

    for ( node:org.neo4j.graphdb.Node <- nodes <- decPath )
    {
       println(node + ": " + node.getProperty("nodeid") + " " + node.getId)
    }
```